# php to update a text file as more data is inputted

Tags: php

I am basically creating a display board that would be shown on multiple monitors. I have it written correct to show just on one monitor, but that is it. Basically, there will be an input page, which will only be shown on 1 monitor, and on all of the other monitors will be the results of the input. The input will be entered in numerous times. For example, and input will be entered in at 8:00, another will be entered at 8:30, etc... On the display, i would like for the displays to get updated with each input. So if input1 was entered at 8:00, it will be displayed out at 8:00, and if input2 was entered in at 8:30, the display would have both input1 and input2, etc... What i am thinking of doing is when an input is entered, to write to a text file. I have code for i can write to a text file, my problem is that i can't update that text file. So input1 stays, and then when i enter in input2, the text file still only shows input1. This is the php code that I am using

```
<?php
$txt = "mydata.txt"; 
if (isset($_POST['dfb']) && isset($_POST['dfb_run']) &&  isset($_POST['dfb_pen']) && isset($_POST['dfb_com'])) { // check if both fields are set
    $fh = fopen($txt, 'w'); 
    $txt=$_POST['dfb'].' - '.$_POST['dfb_run'].' - '.$_POST['dfb_pen'].' - '.$_POST['dfb_com']; 
    fwrite($fh,$txt); // Write information to the file
    fclose($fh); // Close the file
    $file = file ("mydata.txt");
}
?>
```

I figured out why my data was not being written to the text file. I have two fields, labeled as dfb, and dfb_com. Those are readonly fields. I noticed that when i took out those fields from my php script, i was now able to write to the text file. Which brings me to my next question, how do you write a readonly value into a txt file using php? Also, i did also notice that if i want to add in more input values, input1 and input2 would get added again. Is there a way where i can check to see if input1 and input2 have already been posted to the text file? Then that way input3 would be the next line of information.

Comment: Use `$fh = fopen($txt, 'a');` to append to that txte file.

Comment: Unfortunately that still does not work for me.

Comment: So is your problem that you cannot write to `mydata.txt` or you cannot read that file on the other screens?

Comment: Right now, there is data in the text file. My problem currently is i am not able to add more data into the file. I will be having more than 3 fields of data that will be entered. For example, at 8:00 two fields will be inputted with data, and then calculated for that one team. Once i hit submit, all 4 fields will write to the file. At 8:30, the same thing will happen, but it will be for a different team and I would just want to append the data. The display on other screens i am not working on right now as that was part of the whole picture of what i am doing.

Comment: [The manual for `fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) See the `mode` parameter

Comment: You probably want to add a newline at the end of your `$txt` as well so that each update exists on a separate line. Also, it maybe helpful to use a simple `readfile($filename)` to debug the contents of your file before AND after you make edits.

Comment: @wilkesybear if i debug the contents after i make the edits, this would go write after the `fwrite()` correct? then that next line would read `readfile($txt)` because i do not have a variable named filename.

Comment: @novicevba I would do so after the `fclose` line